# What's the shortcut to Device Manager?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-8.1, shortcuts

What is the shortest route to [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager)?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Click on the *Start* menu and type (or type the same in a command-line window, CMD.EXE):

```
devmgmt.msc
```

Or you can just type Device Manager and it should come up.

Comment: Running "devmgmt.msc" is usually pretty straightforward (as is running things like appwiz.cpl, inetcpl.cpl, etc.).

Comment: Instead of the full name, you can also type "dev man" and the Device Manager should be your first result.

Comment: And once you have the name, you can even create a shortcut for it, if you need it frequently.

Comment: Does this work on Windows 8?

Comment: @Tim yes it'll work the same, you just need to access the start screen or use Win + S on Win 8.1 to search globally.

Comment: Windows-R brings up the Run prompt as far back as I remember. devmgmt.msc works there. After you've used it once you just have to type a couple of letters. diskmgmt.msc is disk manager, compmgmt.msc is computer management, in which you can find both of the above.

Answer (score 10):

My typical route to get to the Device Manager window is <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>. This will get you to the System Properties window. Device Manager is just two clicks away:

[image: Screenshot of the System Properties window, with tab Hardware highlighted (where the button for starting Device Manager is).]

Comment: In Windows 7 and up it takes only Win+Pause and one click instead of 2

Answer (score 9):

1. Create a new shortcut.

   [image]
2. Enter `devmgmt.msc` as the target.

   [image]
3. Give the shortcut a name. For example: *Device Manager*.

   [image]
4. Optionally, pin the resulting shortcut to your taskbar for even faster access.

   [image]

Answer (score 7):

Simple. In Windows 10, do <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and press <kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: That mutes sound on Windows 7 (via the Widows Mobility Center).

Comment: It worked for me Windows 10 when I tried it.

Comment: This is language specific. For Finnish W10 it's Win+X, H

Answer (score 4):

Use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> `hdwwiz.cpl`

Or <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> `devmgmt.msc`

Both files open the **Device Manager** window and are located in `%windir%\system32\`.

Though `.cpl` is opened by `control.exe`, and `.msc` by `mmc.exe` executables which are also located in the same path.

PS:

Personally I think `hdwwiz.cpl` is better to memorize as it can be associated with the `appwiz.cpl` counterpart for software, that is the **Programs and Features** window, but despite being a `.cpl` file it opens in **microsoft management console**, meaning it's not a control panel app and therefore should be associated with `mmc.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

The search function in the Vista/7 Start Menu is pretty awesome.  Just type 'Device Manager'.  This works for pretty much any system config applet as long as you have the slightest idea what it's called.  (Try 'hard drive' sometime.)

The old-fashioned way I used in XP, and this still works, is to right-click My Computer in the Start Menu and select 'Manage', which brings up the Computer Management console which has Device Manager, Disk Manager, Event Viewer, etc, readily accessible.

Comment: Yeah, but sadly, the search doesn't work in Win 8 :(

Comment: @GustavoMori - Sure it does (and I just tried it on my Surface to make sure).  You have to look in the Settings subheading, though (apparently this is changed in 8.1 and they've eliminated categorized search by default, but I haven't messed with 8.1 at all yet).  It's probably faster just to do WinKey + X and pick it from the list if you're on the desktop, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the device manager through:

1. The management console snap-in

   ```
   devmgmt.msc
   ```
2. The control panel pane

   ```
   hdwwiz.cpl
   ```

   or

   ```
   rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL hdwwiz.cpl
   ```
3. The device manager dll:

   ```
   rundll32.exe devmgr.dll DeviceManager_Execute
   ```

These all work on Windows 7 through Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows 10 (and [8 it seems](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-device-manager-2626075)) you can press `WIN + X` to open a menu that contains an entry for device manager.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> to open System from Control Panel quickly.