# How to enforce Windows 10 Pro (64 bit) was a resolution of 1280 x 768?

Tags: windows-10, motherboard, resolution, display-driver

I have a problem with setting the screen resolution to 1280 x 768 in Windows 10 Pro.
I have a LG monitor 19M38A-B and the motherboard:
Motherboard Model: GIGABYTE M61SME-S2 and
Motherboard Chipset: nVidia nForce 6100-405

In the picture you can see that there is no Windows 10 this resolution:

[image]

What to do with this?
How to enforce Windows 10 was a resolution of 1280 x 768?

Comment: Via what interface (VGA, HDMI, DVI, DP) are you connected to your display?

Comment: Via VGA only. LG monitor has a socket D-SUB connector DE-15F.

Answer (score 0):

Quick sanity check:

Your [LG monitor](http://www.lg.com/hk_en/monitor/lg-19M38A-B#tech-specs) supports resolution only up to 1366 x 768 and has only one D-Sub jack. Your graphic card is build in the motherboard. Official Gigabyte website states that there is **no** [Windows 10 compatible chipset drivers available](http://www.gigabyte.com.au/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2507#dl) (I highly doubt that these drivers are backward compatible). Then I am not sure how did you installed drivers for the chipset.

You have AMD compatible motherboard with socket AM2+/AM2 with [one of the supported CPU's](http://www.gigabyte.com.au/support-downloads/cpu-support-popup.aspx?pid=2507) on board. Most probably you're lucky enough to run on the processor integrated graphics. Otherwise I have no idea how do you even have the video signal on your monitor.

Your main task would be to figure out what is the current working graphics unit - you can find it in the [device manager](https://superuser.com/a/176457/578626). After that you can go to the `Display adapter properties->Adapter->List all modes->Choose the resolution you want and press OK`. Refer to the step 8 of this [guide](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4910-screen-resolution-display-change-windows-10-a.html).

I would also advise to downgrade back to Windows 7 or whatever version of Windows, for what you can find drivers for. Otherwise you end up in a situation like your with upgraded OS and lost functionality of your hardware.

Or you can use some [third party solutions](http://www.intowindows.com/set-custom-resolution-on-windows-10/) to hack around and see it will work, but most probably this option will mess something up and you'll find yourself in constant search for fixes.

Comment: The solution to this problem to get the right resolution 1280 x 768 display was to exchange for a different model with a larger screen diagonal of 22 inches.