# My Wi-Fi tab is gone. How do I bring it back?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wireless-router, network-adapter

My WiFi tab menu is disappear. I do not know why.

[image]

I use a TP Link Network Adapter to get connected with my wifi. It is connected and I able to browse the net. The problem are the wifi menu and wifi icon/network icon is disappear. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you see anything under Change Adapter Options?

Comment: No. I can't even click the "Change Adapter Options"

Comment: check [Device Manager](https://superuser.com/questions/176456/whats-the-shortcut-to-device-manager) to see if WiFi adapter is disabled, unavailable or has a driver issue [Error codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager). 'Enable' if disabled, 'Disable' and re-'Enable' if driver issue, 'Scan for hardware changes' if unavailable, Restart your pc and check again if the above doesn’t work

Comment: Run the troubleshooter in *Settings  > Network & Internet  > Status > Network troubleshooter*.

Comment: Also [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) would help to verify the state of your system.

Comment: I end up reinstall my OS. If you have the same experience like me, never do network reset unless you prepare for not connected to the net.

Answer (score 1):

Press win + r then inputs `ncpa.cpl` and then see the available adapter's if WiFi is still there try to disable-enable it by right-click the WiFi adapter.

If it isn't their you have to reinstall the WiFi drives...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I've had many experiences with TP-Link adaptors not working properly. What helped me 90% of the time was the following:

1. Go into the device manager (press Win+R and enter `devmgmt.msc`)
2. Uninstall the drivers.
3. Unplug the adaptor and restart the computer.
4. When it is booted up plug it back in and then Windows should start installing the proper drivers.

The other 10% were somehow fixed by installing all available updates.

---

You could also go into the Eventviewer (press Win+R and enter `eventvwr.msc`) and search for error messages that might show you some more information as to why the adaptor or its drivers failed exactly.